# Binary search tree in java, boolean

Tags: java, boolean

In this code, I don't undertand this line  `loEs = (actual.left == null && actual.right == null);`
How is this returning a loEs= true?

```
public boolean isLeaf(E e) { 
   return isLeaf(e, this.root); 
}
protected boolean isLeaf(E e, NBT<E> actual) {
   boolean loEs = false;
   if (actual != null) {
       int res = actual.data.compareTo(e); 
       if (res == 0)      loEs = (actual.left == null && actual.right == null);
       else if (res > 0)  loEs = isLeaf(e, actual.left);
       else                loEs = isLeaf(e, actual.right); 
   }
   return loEs;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

loEs will be assigned with a boolean that depends on two conditions :

- actual.left == null
- actual.right == null

Since the operand is &&, both actual.left == null AND actual.right == null must be true in order for loEs to be true.

Basically there's 4 possibilites :

```
actual.left == null AND actual.right == null : loEs == true
actual.left != null AND actual.right == null : loEs == false
actual.left == null AND actual.right != null : loEs = false
actual.left != null AND actual.right != null : loEs = false
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `loEs = (actual.left == null && actual.right == null);` assigns a boolean to the field `loEs`. The expression `(actual.left == null && actual.right == null)` is a test which return `true` or `false`.

It is equivalent to :

```
if (actual.left == null && actual.right == null) {
    loEs = true;
} else {
    loEs = false;
}
```

So, if `actual.left` equals `null` AND `actual.right` equals `null` then the `loEs` field equals `true`. It is the only case where the field equals `true`.

Comment: ah ok, so we could have just put if (res==0 && actual.left == null && actual.right == null)  loEs = true;  ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But this would force you to write an "else { loEs = false }", whereas here you can assign true or false in one line.